# Kann man »folgende|r|s« mit Artikel schreiben?

Tags: grammar, adjective, article

> Bitte beachten Sie folgende Regeln.
> Bitte beachten Sie die folgenden Regeln.
>
> Bitte beachten Sie alle Punkte der folgenden Regeln.
> Bitte beachten Sie alle Punkte folgender Regeln.

Welche Sätze sind richtig?

Kann man *folgende|r|s* mit Artikel schreiben?

Comment: Ohne Artikel wird 'folgende' auch häufig im Imperativ verwendet: "Folgende Regeln sind zu beachten:" (kann ich mir gut auf Schildern zB in Hausfluren, Vereinsräumen, Camping-Plätzen etc. vorstellen)

Answer (score 7):

Ja, das kann man. Das Besondere an 'folgende' ist, daß man den Artikel gut *fortlassen* kann:

> Beachten Sie die folgenden Sicherheitshinweise: - OK
>
> Beachten Sie folgende Sicherheitshinweise: - OK
>
> Beachten Sie die goldenen Verzierungen.  - OK
>
> Beachten Sie goldene Verzierungen.  - weniger OK

Das vierte Beispiel impliziert, daß goldene Verzierungen im Land umgehen und man sich vor ihnen hüten sollte, während das dritte einfach nur auf die in der Situation präsenten Verzierungen verweist. Das Adjektiv übernimmt also selbst einen Teil der Rolle, die sonst der bestimmte Artikel ausfüllt. Einige verwandte wie etwa 'untenstehende' oder 'nachfolgende' zeigen dasselbe Verhalten.

Comment: "Bitte beachten Sie alle Punkte folgender Regeln." ist m.W.n 100% richtig ('OK'), wird aber vermutlich eher selten verwendet.

Answer (score 1):

Die(3.Person Plural) folgenden Sätze sind alle korrekt.

Der folgende Satz ist auch korrekt.

Das folgende Beispiel ebenso.

Die folgende Phrase stimmt.